# Python: Visualize shop locations based on distance between pairs of shops (3 column dataframe)

Tags: python, dataframe, location, visualization, distance

Given is a dataframe *distances* looking like this (below is a simplified version with only 4 shops):

```
shopID_1  shopID_2   distance
0         1          14
0         2          12
0         3          19
1         2          15
1         3          13
2         3          12
```

What is a nice way to visualize the shops (with their distance) on a map?

Comment: What would you like to see in your map?

Comment: If you only have pairwise distances, maybe some sort of weighted graph representation.

Comment: You said "on a map" ... does that mean you intend to infer the relative locations of all of the shops to make the distance table work out?  That seems like a difficult problem.  Do you have shop locations in any format?

Comment: I would like to present the relative distances of the stores to each other in a space. So the stores can simply represent points in a white space. The aim is rather a descriptive statistic (e.g. visually showing that there are many stores close to store 2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example some manifold learning as described here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html#multi-dimensional-scaling-mds (the API is described in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.MDS.html#sklearn.manifold.MDS ).

These method are a bit more general than what you want but should work well  (your problem, if it is indeed as you described, **has** an exact 2D solution).